# How prove The triangle inequality $\rho{(a,b)}\le \rho{(a,c)}+\rho{(c,b)}$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers,and such
>   $$|a|<1,|b|<1,|c|<1$$
>
> let $$\rho{(x,y)}=\left|\dfrac{x-y}{1-\overline{x}y}\right|$$
>
> show that 
>   $$\rho{(a,b)}\le \rho{(a,c)}+\rho{(c,b)}$$

we only prove

$$\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|\le \left|\dfrac{a-c}{1-\overline{a}c}\right|+\left|\dfrac{c-b}{1-\overline{c}b}\right|,|a|,|b|,|c|<1$$

then I can't ,

I  have found this book ,[page 38](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=5IAWL8MUGtQC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=pseudohyperbolic+metric+triangle+inequality&source=bl&ots=9xKQv3SILN&sig=qR-SaL86ISwfbGNTqcWkrPOf5iI&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=_Ng7VLb4MJbqoATH-YKACw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=pseudohyperbolic%20metric%20triangle%20inequality&f=false),this book say this triangle inequality is less obvious,so I can't see anywhere have this inequality solution,

can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD0QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucla.edu%2F~twg%2Fkorea.pdf&ei=-LM7VMzSCNXi8AXYtYGACA&usg=AFQjCNFXep43MRrdP_rZbQAoIZl7-IXX3A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference is the book you referred :

**Step 1** : Let $$ f(x,y)  :=\frac{x-y}{1-\overline{x} y } $$

From a routine computation we have $$ |f( f(x,y),f(x,z)) | = |f(y,z)
|$$

Since $$
 |f(a,b)| = |f(f(c,a),f(c,b))| = \bigg| \frac{ f(c,a) -
 f(c,b)}{1-\overline{f(c,a)} f(c,b)} \bigg| $$ we have a claim $$    \bigg| \frac{ f(c,a) -
 f(c,b)}{1-\overline{f(c,a)} f(c,b)} \bigg|\leq |  f(c,a) | +
 |
 f(c,b) |\ (1)$$

**Step 2** : $$|x|,\ |y| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x,y)| <1$$

Proof : It is followed from a direct computation.

**Step 3** : That is if
$v:= f(c,a),\ w:= f(c,b) $ then we have
$$
 |v-w|\leq |v-|v|^2 w| +|w-|w|^2v |\ (2) \Leftrightarrow (1)$$

If $v:=v_1+iv_2,\ w:=w_1+iw_2$ then $$ \sqrt{(v_1-w_1)^2 +
 (v_2-w_2)^2} \leq \sqrt{(v_1-|v|^2w_1)^2 +
 (v_2-|v|^2w_2)^2} $$ $$+\sqrt{ (w_1-|w|^2v_1)^2 +
  (w_2-|w|^2v_2)^2 } \ (3)\Leftrightarrow (2) $$

**Case 1** : $v_1w_1 \geq 0$ Then

$$ 0\leq |w|^4 v_1^2 + |v|^4 w_1^2- 2v_1w_1 (|v|^2+
 |w|^2-1)\Leftrightarrow  $$

$$0\leq (|w|^2 v_1 - |v|^2 w_1)^2 + 2v_1w_1 (1-|v|^2)(1- |w|^2)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
  (v_1-w_1)^2 \leq (v_1-|v|^2w_1)^2 +
(w_1-|w|^2v_1)^2
$$

**Case 2** : $v_1=-nw_1,\ n>0,\ v_2w_2 \geq 0$ Then $$
  (v_1-w_1)^2=(n+1)^2w_1^2, $$ $$  (v_1-|v|^2w_1)^2 +
(w_1-|w|^2v_1)^2  +2 |v_1-|v|^2w_1 || w_1-|w|^2v_1 | \geq $$ $$
(n+n^2w_1^2)^2w_1^2 +(1+nw_1^2)^2w_1^2 +
2(n+n^2w_1^2)(1+nw_1^2)w_1^2
$$

That is, we proved the following :

$$ (v_1-w_1)^2  \leq  (v_1-|v|^2w_1)^2  + (w_1-|w|^2v_1)^2 + 2
|v_1-|v|^2w_1 || w_1-|w|^2v_1 | $$

**Case 3** : $v_1=-nw_1,\ v_2=-mw_2,\ n,\ m >0$

Note that
$$
nw_1^2+ mw_2^2 \leq \sqrt{n^2w_1^4 + (n^2+m^2)w_1^2 w_2^2 +
m^2w_2^4} $$

If we replace $ v_1=-nw_1,\ v_2=-mw_2$ in (3), then we have (3) from direct
computation. 
So we complete the proof.